# Webapi 2 attribute routing not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a method in Account controller (using RoutePrefix("api/Account") that I want to respond to api/users instead of api/account, so I used the '~' to override it:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("~api/users/{name:alpha}/exists")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UserExists(string name)
{
    var res = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(name);
    if (res != null) 
       return Ok();
       return BadRequest();
}


So when I try it out I get the response: 
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:21975/api/users/johndoe/exists'
```

By all means this should work but its not for some reason, can anyone suggest why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The route needs to be...

```
[Route("~/api/users/{name:alpha}/exists")]
```

Comment: Was just about to post this. You're missing the first `/` after the relative root.